# Android studio emulator not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I  Run the android program in android studio , emulator will appear for 1 second then disappear.. How to solve this problem? And it shows the error " waiting for the device to come online "

Comment: I suggest starting the emulator by itself. Wait for it to boot completely before running your app.

Comment: I waited for a long time and it doen,'t appear again.

Comment: open the AVD dialog and start it

Answer (score 1):

Try this. go to the AVD manager and select the devices and stop them by the right click menu. Then wipe data and start cold boot now option

```
AVD Manager=> select the emulator => select stop & Wipe data & Cold boot now
```

Then try running the app again.